# Как изменить значение в массиве, с условием по ключу

Tags: php

Добрый день. Не получается догнать, как сделать. Формируется массив динамически. Он может быть таким

1.

```
[f_i] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => fld_img
                [2] => page
                [3] => article
            )

        [2] => 0
    )
```

2.

```
[f_i] => Array
    (
        [1] => 0

        [2] => 0
```

3.

```
 [f_i] => Array
     (
        [1] => 0

        [2] => Array
            (
                [1] => fld_img2
                [2] => page
                [3] => article
            )
    )
```

Взял всего с двумя ключами и 4 состояниями. Мне нужно преобразовать массив к такому виду.

Если значение == 0, то не трогать. Если значение является массивом, то значение  равно ключу. То есть должно получится, так в первом случае.

1.

```
[f_i] => Array
    (
        [1] => 1

        [2] => 0
    )
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пройти массив циклом [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) и проверить значения его элементов функцией [is_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-array.php). Если это массив, заменяем его на ключ. Предположим что $arr это ваш массив, тогда цикл будет выглядеть так:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value))
        $arr[$key] = $key;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает. Не ожидал, что так быстро ответят. Жмякнуть плюс пока не могу, рейтинг меньше 15. Про is_array  как то забыл совсем. Занимался фигней в общем. Еще раз спасибо, пиво бы проставил :)

Comment: Отлично! Рад помочь. Автор вопроса может отметить ответ как правильный без ограничений по рейтингу ;)

Comment: [ссылка]http://prntscr.com/c4sst9  Я правильно сделал? Извините, первый раз задаю вопросы.

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо :)

Comment: И Вам спасибо. Очень выручили, сидел тупил.